# How to sort output of the find command in a script

Tags: bash

I have the following simple script to find all directories (at a depth of 2) that were added in the last N days...

```
#!/bin/bash
DAYS_PRIOR=180
DIR='/mydir'
FILES=`find $DIR -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime -$DAYS_PRIOR -printf '%f\\\n'`
echo
echo "Files added in the last $DAYS_PRIOR days:"
echo
echo -e $FILES
echo
```

To get it to add newlines I had to double-escape the printf and use `echo -e`.  That seems odd to me but it was the only way I could get it to print one directory per line on the output.

Everything works up to this point and I get a list of directories as expected.  Now I want to sort the list alphabetically.  I tried changing the printf in the find command to...

```
FILES=`find <xxx> -printf '%f\\\n' | sort`
```

however this doesn't sort the directory names.  Based on other posts I tried the following..

```
FILES=`find <xxx> -printf %f\\\n | sort -t '\0' | awk -F '\0' '{print $0; print "\\\n"}'`
```

This is very close but leaves an extra space at the start of each line and seems horribly awkward.

Is there a simple method to add a sort to the original `find` command?

Comment: could you please paste the partial output of first find command?. I don't see issues in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: double-quote your variable references! When you use `echo -e $FILES`, the variable `FILE`'s value gets split into "words" based on whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines), and then `echo` sticks those words back together with spaces between them. This has the effect of converting newlines into spaces. In order to wind up with newlines at the end, you're having to use `\n` instead of a true newline, and use `echo -e` to convert it. Just use real newlines, and put double-quotes around the variable reference to avoid all this mess:

```
FILES=$(find "$DIR" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime "-$DAYS_PRIOR" -printf '%f\n')
# ...
echo "$FILES"
```

Note that I put double-quotes around *all* variable references, since this is almost always a good idea. I also used `$( )` instead of backticks -- it's easier to read, and avoids some parsing oddities that backticks have.

Anyway, with this format you're using proper newlines throughout, so piping through `sort` should work as expected.

BTW, I'd also recommend switching from uppercase variable names to lower- or mixed-case names, since there are a bunch of all-caps names that have special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of them bad things can happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but on my system (Ubuntu 18.04) the above prints all directories on the same line, no newline in the output.  If I add sort to it, the output is correctly sorted but everything is still on the same line.  I also tried this with the double-escape of the -printf %f\n but that doesn't add newlines either.

Comment: Oops. Ignore the above comment, I missed something.  This does work.  Thanks for the input.